# stringbuilder add initial character to each new line

Tags: c#

Currently I have a `StringBuilder` with some lines

```
        StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder()
            .AppendLine("- one")
            .AppendLine("- two")
            .AppendLine("- three");
```

and I would like to setup the `"- "` character for each new line. Pseudo code:

```
        StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder()
            .SetNewLineInitialCharacter("- ")
            .AppendLine("one")
            .AppendLine("two")
            .AppendLine("three");
```

I don't think `Insert` or `Replace` are methods I am looking for. I know a loop could do the trick but there is no need for it and I'm just asking if there is a way setting up `"- "` for one single time.

Comment: Just add the character on each call. Or use `AppendFormat`, eg `AppendFormat("- {0}",whatever)`. Even `AppendLine($"- {whatever}")`

Comment: You can create your own class of stringbuilder inheritance from stringbuilder and additional options

Comment: You could also write an extension method for StringBuilder

Comment: `StringBuilder`'s job is to create one big string without generating temporary strings and excessive reallocations. You are asking for something that will generate a specific layout.

Comment: @Kaspar that would be a bad idea - the result wouldn't only try to do *two* different things (generate strings and layouts), it would also break the expected behaviour of the base class. It's impossible though because `StringBuilder` is sealed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes you are right, I was not checked if it is sealead, also about layour and strings, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a wrapped StringBuilder:

```
public class StringBuilderWrapper
{
    private readonly string _prefix;
    private readonly StringBuilder _builder;

    public StringBuilderWrapper(StringBuilder builder, string prefix)
    {
        _prefix = prefix;
        _builder = builder;
    }

    public StringBuilderWrapper AppendLine(string line)
    {
        _builder.Append(_prefix);
        _builder.AppendLine(line);

        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _builder.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Which, for convenience, you can return from an extension method:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilderWrapper SetNewLineInitialCharacter(this StringBuilder builder, string prefix)
    {
        return new StringBuilderWrapper(builder, prefix);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var output = new StringBuilder()
    .SetNewLineInitialCharacter("- ")
    .AppendLine("one")
    .AppendLine("two")
    .AppendLine("three");

var outputString = output.ToString();
```

Which outputs:

```
- one
- two
- three
```

Without the extension method, you'd call it like this:

```
var output = new StringBuilderWrapper(new StringBuilder(), "- ")
    .AppendLine("one")
    .AppendLine("two")
    .AppendLine("three");
```

Answer (score 4):

One of many ways to do this would be to wrap the StringBuilder in a separate class.

```
void Main()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var foo = new MyStringBuilder(sb, "- ")
            .AppendLine("one")
            .AppendLine("two")
            .AppendLine("three");

    var result = sb.ToString();
}

public class MyStringBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder _sb;
    private string _linePrefix;

    public MyStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb, string linePrefix)
    {
            _sb = sb;
            _linePrefix = linePrefix;
    }

    public MyStringBuilder AppendLine(string line)
    {
        _sb.Append(_linePrefix);
        _sb.AppendLine(line);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {   
       return _sb.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you copy-pasted your answer from @CodeCaster's one?

Comment: @vasily.sib Or is he a copy of mine? ;-) When I wrote this CodeCaster's answer did not look as it does now.

Comment: [CodeCaster's revision#2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53430019/2) at `2018-11-22 11:32:39Z` [Your revision#1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53430081/1) at `2018-11-22 11:34:45Z` you are almost 2 minutes late

Comment: @vasily.sib no plagiarism from my side and I don't suspect Magnus either, this "adapter pattern" is a pretty common pattern to add functionality to a sealed class.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be something like that

```
public class CustomStringBuilder 
{
    private StringBuilder _builder;
    private string _prefix;

    public CustomStringBuilder (StringBuilder builder, string prefix)
    {
            _builder = builder;
            _prefix = prefix;
    }

    public CustomStringBuilder CustomAppendLine(string text)
    {
        _builder .Append(_prefix);
        _builder .AppendLine(text);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _builder.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

and you could call it like that:

```
CustomStringBuilderfoo = new CustomStringBuilder(new StringBuilder(), "- ")
            .CustomAppendLine ("one")
            .CustomAppendLine ("two")
            .CustomAppendLine ("three");
```

Comment: @John well you fixed everyone's answer... :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, everyone beat me to giving one so it's the least I could do lol